# 403 Forbidden when saving form

Tags: sitecore-forms

I followed the steps in the main Sitecore site to try and make a form using Sitecore 9, here

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/90/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/creating_forms/create_a_new_form

However, whenever i click "save", i get an error message "an error has occurred", and it won't save.

I've checked the console, apparently every time i click "save" this error appears [image]

Any tips on how to fix this would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the error it looks like the new forms in Sitecore 9 are using the Sitecore item api in order to save the form and the error your seeing is due to failing authentication.

can you use postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) to post a test to the following endpoint to try and login and see if the item api is working correctly?:

https://sitecore1.local/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login

You should be able to import this curl command into postman:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://sitecore1.local/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'postman-token: 0de63dfb-7712-bc08-0ba0-abb85f33d855' \
  -d 'username=admin&password=b&domain=sitecore&database=master'
```

I'm assuming your local username and password here are admin/b so update these if not.

If the above request doesn't work make sure you set up a local self signed cert in IIS and are using Sitecore under HTTPS: https://dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2017/01/11/creating-self-signed-ssl-certificate-developing-testing-iis/

The item API requires requests to be under https in order to work. Once you have done this you should find the request above works.

Comment: I sent the request using postman, I got the following error response:
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://sitecore1.local/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login.

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer. try adding a self signed cert and using that

Comment: I've followed the steps in the link, added the certificate, but I'm still facing the same error, i still get 403 in sitecore and "could not get any response" in postman

Comment: Ok can you use Sitecore ok under https: https://sitecore1.local ?

Comment: If i enter https in the address bar "https://sitecore1.local/sitecore" works, but the https is mostly useless since it still tells me my connection is not secure.. It says the certificate is invalid for some reason

Comment: Yeah it will throw that error as it is non secure since it's a self signed cert. Can you accept the ssl error and ignore it in chrome and then see if enabling interceptor in Postman gets past this issue and lets you login without a 403 against the api in Postman? https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/interceptor_extension

Comment: can you please tell me how to accept the ssl error and ignore it?

Comment: choose the “Advanced” link, then choose “Proceed to <link> (unsafe)“: https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-bypass-your-connection-is-not-private-message

Comment: okay, so that didn't work either,,but as a last resort i tried deleting the cookies of sitecore1.local (my local site), and restarting the browser, and that finally did the trick! it works now, thanks alot!

Comment: Cool, glad you managed to solve this issue anyway.

Comment: Had same issue and indeed deleting cookies helped...

Comment: Getting this issue with Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8.  Indeed deleting cookies makes the issue go away, but then it crops up again after making a few more changes until you once again delete the cookies :(  We are finding that the form saves fine for a few goes and then stops working.