# Can't save form in form builder

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am facing a weird issue in saving the form in the form builder. The error is:

[image]

It's a plain vanilla sitecore 9.1 instance. I reindexed all the indexes.I checked the logs but none is written. Has anyone faced such an issue?

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat : Yes, I am getting the error 403 forbidden, I am going through this link https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11586/403-forbidden-when-saving-form. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try to delete cookies @Varun?

Comment: are you on using a correct SSL certificate? is this your local or any other environment?

Comment: @PeterProcházka Thanks. Deleting cookies worked.

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat thanks for your time and help